# Multi-column Deep Neural Networks for Image Classification Paper

Tags: classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I am trying to reproduce the results of https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2745 that is using a Deep Convolutional Neural Network architecture for image classification. 
[image]

Convolutional layer L2 (all 20 maps) is fully connected to L3 (to all 40 maps) via 800 filters. Do you know how to model this in Keras or TensorFlow?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I contacted to the first author of the paper and it turned out that L2 is fully connected to L3 (in a convolutional way). Now the question is how can I make this model is Keras or TensorFlow? I couldn't find a way to model fully connected convolutional to convolutional layer.

Comment: I think Keras does that automatically, the full connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply define a new convolutional layer with the desired number of filters?

```
yourmodel.add(Conv2D(800, (5, 5), 
                 padding='same', 
                 activation='relu'))
```

Comment: Can you expand somewhat your answer?

Comment: The example I posted was in Keras. You define a model of the _Sequential_ class and simply add layers with specific parameters.

For the image from the paper the layers would be:

L1 Convolution(20 filters, 4x4),
L2 MaxPooling,
L3 Convolution (800 filters, 5x5),
L4 MaxPooling,
L5 Fully Connected layer,
output.

The code I wrote would be layer L3.

_Note: I haven't read the paper, the number of filters and dimensions is what I understand from the posted image._

Comment: yes thanks! The correct answer is:
`yourmodel.add(Conv2D(40, (5, 5), 
                 padding='same', 
                 activation='relu'))`